# Undefined variable: delete in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Test\HRMS\try\search1.php on line 61

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am trying very hard for the last 2 hours but am not able to understand.  Why am I getting undefined variable in DELETE.  Please please look in to my code and help me out.

My main intention is to delete multiple rows at once using checkboxes.

When I am trying to run the below codes it gives me following errors:

```
Undefined variable: delete in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Test\HRMS\try\search1.php on line 61
```

But I already have used it in following way:

```
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"></td>
```

Thanks in advance.

my php codes :

```
  <?php
  $host="localhost"; // Host name
  $username="a"; // Mysql username
  $password="a"; // Mysql password
  $db_name="b"; // Database name
  $tbl_name="emp_info"; // Table name

  // Connect to server and select databse.
  mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
  mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

  $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);

  $count=mysql_num_rows($result);

  ?>
  <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
  <td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
  <tr>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Delete multiple rows in mysql</strong> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Id</strong></td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Name</strong></td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Password</strong></td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Address</strong></td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Source</strong></td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>salary</strong></td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Zip</strong></td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Mobile</strong></td>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Email</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  ?>
  <tr>
  <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['eid']; ?>"></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['eid']; ?></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['ename']; ?></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['password']; ?></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['address']; ?></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['source']; ?></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['salary']; ?></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['zip']; ?></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['mobile']; ?></td>
  <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  <tr>
  <td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete"></td>
  </tr>
  <?php
  // Check if delete button active, start this
  if($delete){
  for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
  $del_id = $checkbox[$i];
  $sql = "DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE eid='$del_id'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  }

  // if successful redirect to search1.php
  if($result){
  echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=search1.php\">";
  }
  }
  mysql_close();
  ?>
  </table>
  </form>
  </td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before looping results from MySQL result variable, you should **ALWAYS** have to make sure that it contain any values:

```
if($total > 0)
{
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        //your code goes here
    }
}
```

Another issue you have here, is same as in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830505/undefined-variable-error-in-my-php-script/8830706#8830706), variable $delete is not defined, based on your code, it is not clear where it is coming from.

So, if `$delete` is actually a `$_POST` variable, your `if` statement should look like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){}
```

Another issue, `$checkbox` it is not defined to. I would recommend you to read more about [`filter_input`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) method as it can be very handy on sanitizing user submitted data.

Also you are using incorrect html tags instead of:

```
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Id</strong></td>
```

use correct `TD` tag which aligns text in center and makes it bold, also bgcolor should be defined in CSS file.

```
<th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Id</th>
```

Your final code should look like this:

```
<?php
$host = "localhost"; // Host name
$username = "a"; // Mysql username
$password = "a"; // Mysql password
$db_name = "b"; // Database name
$tbl_name = "emp_info"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Make sure that delete action was called using
//$delete = isset($_POST['delete']);
//OR
//$delete = array_key_exists('delete', $_POST);
//OR
$delete = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'delete');

$selected = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'checkbox', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY);

if ($delete && !empty($selected))
{

    foreach ($selected as $id)
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE eid='$id'";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }

    // if successful redirect to search1.php
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0;URL=search1.php\">";
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

?>


<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
    <table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
        <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</th>
            <th colspan="9" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Delete multiple rows in mysql</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</th>
            <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Id</th>
            <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Name</th>
            <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Password</th>
            <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Address</th>
            <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Source</th>
            <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">salary</th>
            <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Zip</th>
            <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Mobile</th>
            <th bgcolor="#FFFFFF">Email</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        if ($count)
        {
            while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                        <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value="<?php echo $rows['eid']; ?>">
                    </td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['eid']; ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['ename']; ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['password']; ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['address']; ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['source']; ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['salary']; ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['zip']; ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['mobile']; ?></td>
                    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['email']; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
        }
        mysql_close();
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="10" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                <input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

**Please don't just copy paste it, read it and try to understand it.**

Comment: when I apply isset it does not show any error but it is not deleting when I click on delete button :(

Comment: It is not showing any error but its still not deleting. My column field name is eid which is same; m keeping in the query. It should match to the table even though I do not know where is it going wrong. If u do little more with these codes then this must be working as it did yesterday. Please... check the codes... Thanks in advance...

Comment: You had so many issues that I forgot to place delete functionality in beginning of your code. Give it a try again and try to understand why it's written this way.

Comment: @ Nazariy :Thanks a lot for your precious time... I checked your codes... Its becoming quite difficult for me to understand why is it not deleting from the table when m using correct column name :( cheers...

Comment: try to inspect your html output and make sure that checkbox value is set in HTML SOURCE, also if you are using MySQL InnoDB tables and it has some foreign keys linked from another table, it might prevent from removing records.

Comment: @ Nazariy : Hi  Nazariy... I must appreciate and thank you for your awesome effort and help for me. You always have given me perfect code. It was my mistake I didn't understand. In your code I just need to change id="checkbox" to id="checkbox[]". Its working. Thank you Sooooo much  Nazariy. we newbie trust This site
(stackoverflow) because of you all guys. Thanks once again. :)

Comment: @ Nazariy : 1 small and last query to you. This filter function   "FILTER_VALIDATE_INT"  is preventing from reading "VARCHAR" value from the "eid" column. In case if that column consists of only integer value this code is working perfectly. But employee-id is mixed of characters and numbers. And when m trying with that; this code is not helping me out. I checked with few other filtering options but it didn't work. You are my last hope. This is third day with this code. Hope it will be done today. :( Please check the codes one last time...

Answer (score 3):

Register globals is off (and this is good) so the line

```
if($delete){
```

should be

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) { ...
```

Moreover you need to restructure your code as it's absolutely unnecessery to make a select query to database when you have a post request to delete records.

Here is a complete code you need. Just replace yours with this one.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);

$host = "localhost"; // Host name
$username = "a"; // Mysql username
$password = "a"; // Mysql password
$db_name = "b"; // Database name
$tbl_name = "emp_info"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Delete records
if (isset($_POST['delete']))
{
    // Concatenate ids in a comma-separated string
    $ids = implode(',', $_POST['checkbox']);

    if (!empty($ids))
    {
        $sql = "DELETE FROM $tbl_name WHERE eid IN ($ids)";
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    }

    // Redirect back
    header('Location: search1.php');
    die();
}

// Select records
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

?>
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form name="form1" method="post" action="">
                <table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Delete multiple rows in mysql</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Id</strong></td>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Name</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                            <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]"
                                   value="<?php echo $rows['eid']; ?>">
                        </td>
                        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['eid']; ?></td>
                        <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><?php echo $rows['ename']; ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
                            <input name="delete" type="submit" id="delete" value="Delete">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the attention but it is still showing the same error...   Notice: Undefined variable: delete in C:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\Test\HRMS\try\search1.php on line 61 :(

Comment: I just copied and pasted your code /*[if ($_POST['delete']) { ]*/ in place of my code but it is showing the same error...

Comment: You suppose to make sure that `$_POST['delete']` is defined using `isset` or `array_key_exists` in case `$_POST['delete'] = NULL`

Comment: Absolutely there should be `isset`.

Comment: @Nazariy :  I applied isset; now  it is not showing any error but it is not deleting even when I click on delete button :(

Comment: Again it's not deleting because what is `$checkbox` variable? It should be $_POST['checkbox']. I will make a complete working example in a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks for your precious time. I am looking on your code very carefully. Where clause is good even though m getting folowing error :  Unknown column '1mw103' in 'where clause'

Comment: Double check everything to match your table field names etc. This example is pretty simple not to work (if everything is done properly). I ran it on my own and all is fine.

Comment: @dfsq Your code is working only when field (eid) contains integer (1 or 2...) value. If it (eid) contains mixed of numbers and characters (1mw103) then its not working. It is showing the same error (error : Unknown column '1mw103' in 'where clause ). And in case of only integer, although I select only one checkbox; it is deleting entire table contents. :(

Comment: Well it's supposed that eid is unique integer id (which is natural, btw). My code is just a draft since I'm unaware of you specific DB structure. Fill free to adjust it to meet your needs.